# Использование filter в angular

Tags: angular2, asp.net-core, angular4

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь сделать выборку данных(например, получить записи, в которых номер равен чему -то. Без filter все работает)

```
http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Student/Students1')
.filter( stud => stud.Phone == 123)
.subscribe(data => {
this.studentTEST = data.json() as Students[];
}, error => console.error(error));
```

Ошибка:

> " Property 'Phone' does not exist on type 'Response' ".

Версия angular была 4.2.5, потом изменил в package.json на 5.1.0 и вроде npm обновил до 5 версии.

Как еще можно отфильтровать данные ?

### Вроде разобрался. (На примере sample data(погода) из шаблона vs angular работает) . Но мои данные из БД не фильтрует

Контроллер:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Students> GetStudent()
{
  return db.Students;
}
```

Интерфейс Students:

```
interface Students {
    Address: string;
    Email: string;
    Phone: string;
    StdName: string;
}
```

Запрос:

```
http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Student/Students1')                           
.subscribe(result => {
this.std = (result as Students[]).filter(s => s.Email === "ffff");
}, error => console.error(error));
```

Если сделать 
`filter(std => std.Email != "ffff")` , например, то выводит все, но если попытаться отфильтровать что-то, то ничего не выводит

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте! Вы применяете `filter` к потоку, а не к данным.

```
    http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Student/Students1')
     .map( data => data.json().filter(s => s.Phone === 123))
     .subscribe(data => {
       this.studentTEST = data as Students[];
     }, error => console.error(error));
```

Надеюсь это решение Вам подойдет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ошибка " Parameter 's' implicitly has an 'any' type."

Comment: Вам нужно указать тип для переменной `s`.

Comment: Ошибок теперь нет, но и данных никаких не выводит....

Comment: Может как - то по другому отфильтровать можно?

Comment: Скажите, Вы воспользовались советами, которые Вам дали в англоязычном сообществе? В примере кода я видела, что Вы закомментировали `subscribe`, пожалуйста, не забудь раскомментировать его перед тем как тестировать. Потому что иначе Observable не сработает. Надеюсь, Вы так же вынесете этот метод в сервис. Я пыталась воспроизвести ошибку, но у меня не получилось :(
Будем разбираться до конца.)

Comment: Добавил в описание , посмотрите , пожалуйста